# Converting H/T to 0/1 binary array

Tags: python

I’ve loaded a sample using the code:

```
Data = np.load(sample_1.npy)
```

I need to convert the data points from H/T (coin tosses) to 0/1 (binary array). Not sure what code would work for this? I’ve tried googling answers and they haven’t worked.

Comment: Please provide example data.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Asking so I can provide it.

Comment: @PythonBeginner Give an example to show what you expect in output for a sample input.

Comment: I mean some data that we can use to test potential solutions and which would clarify what your data is. Some code like `Data = 'HTHTT'`, but with an array like you actually have it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an array with "H" and "T" as values, you could try that:

```
Data = np.array([0 if x == "H" else 1 for x in Data])
```